# ordered list does not work on IE7 (<ol><li)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to create an ordered list on IE7 but for some reason does not work.
Does anybody knows why this can be?
**Update**

The issue is that I cant see the numbers, thanks.

Thanks.

eg.

```
<ol>
 <li></li>
 <li><li>
</ol>
```

**Update**
As an example I saw this page where if you look at it on IE7 you wont see de numbers, but if you look at it on any other (but not ie) you will see the numbers.

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html

Thanks

Comment: I have them complete on my code, sorry this was an example.
I correct them now.Thanks

Comment: The issue is that I cant see the numbers :-(.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) works fine in all browsers from IE6 and up (IE6/7/8, FF2/3, Safari3, Chrome4, Opera9).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2401705</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1
            <li>Item 2
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

It even works when I tried to replace the `</ol>` by the syntactically invalid `<ol>`. So, your problem lies somewhere else. You really need to elaborate the "Doesn't work" in *more detail*. What exactly happens? What exactly happens *not*? Preferably edit your question to include an SSCCE (like above) and try to ask the question the [smart way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Note, in contrary to what others say, a non-closing `<li>` is syntactically valid in normal HTML. It's indeed invalid in XHTML, but I don't see any reason to use XHTML unless you're using a component based MVC framework or some other XML based tool to generate HTML pages.

**Update**: you thus don't see the numbers. Apparently you've set the `margin` of the `ol` to zero. This way they will get out of the view. The following SSCCE demonstrates it. It indeed fails in IE6/7.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2401705 - IE6/7 problem</title>
        <style>ol { margin: 0; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1
            <li>Item 2
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't set the margin to 0. This may also be caused by a so-called CSS reset sheet. Don't use them, just remember to specify the margins for all block elements yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I did not remember the reset sheet, you are right they are dangerous. :-) +1.

Comment: They're only dangerous if you don't understand what they're doing :)

Answer (score 5):

You may also have to give your ordered list a margin-left to see the numbers in IE7.  Try this:

```
<ol style="margin-left:25px;"> 
 <li>test1</li> 
 <li>test2</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not seeing the numbers at all, it's likely you need to set a margin or padding on the ol element, e.g.

```
ol {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

You might also need to set `list-style: decimal;`.

There's also some CSS bugs that can have a weird effect on ordered lists in older versions of IE. The symptom is usually the counter resetting to 1 for every item. Are you seeing that?

Answer (score 2):

Complete your tags and it should be fine:

```
<ol>
 <li>blah</li>
 <li>ha</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you close your `<li>` tags:

```
<ol>
  <li>first thing</li>
  <li>second thing</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the </li> was optional in HTML (though it's obviously not in XHTML).

Comment: Well the original question was a little short on details :-)

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I felt none of the answers solved my case:

```
ol {list-style-position:inside;}
li {display:list-item;}

<ol>
   <li>foo</li>
   <li>bar</li>
</ol>
```

- ```
  list-style-position: inside
  ```

  Fixes the list so that the numbers appear (don't use margin)
- ```
  display:list-item
  ```

  When list elements have either a width, or layout (? I forget), IE7 has a numbering bug and all list elements show as `1.`; this fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this old question. For me the solution was to remove the float:left declaration I had on my ol-tag. Posting it here in case someone finds it useful.

Example code that reproduces this IE7-behavior:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2401705 - IE6/7 problem</title>
    <style type="text/css">ol { float:left; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ol>
</body>
```