# IE 8 ordered list type a fix

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a list and i am using

```
<ol type="a">

<li> apple </li>
<li> mango </li>
<li> banana </li>

</ol>
```

Now In chrome it look ok

```
a. apple
b. mango
c. banana
```

but In IE 8

```
a. apple
a. mango 
a. banana
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this for IE 8

Comment: How are javascript and jquery and css related to the issue? The code in the question does not contain any of them, though they may relate to the real problem.

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted. People are now just making guesses that CSS settings equivalent to `type="a"` would solve the problem (there is no problem to be solved in the code).

Comment: Can you please check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKtE6/2/)..!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problem of `hasLayout`, so this problem is likely to be a specific styling issue. ok lets solve this,

Applying CSS `display:list-item` to the `<li>` element and `list-style-type: lower-alpha` to the `<ol>` element.

#### CSS

```
ol{
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
li{
    display:list-item;
}
```

if not work above code you should also apply `padding-left` and `margin-left` to the `<ol>` container.

#### CSS

```
ol {
   margin-left: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

this two help you, hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

add `class="d"`

```
<ol type="a" class="d">

<li> apple </li>
<li> mango </li>
<li> banana </li>

</ol>
```

and css
define `margin` and use `list-style`

```
ol.d {
   list-style-type:lower-alpha;
   margin-left:25px;
   /*padding: 20px;*/
   list-style-position:inside;}
li {
   display:list-item;
   }
```

Comment: Could you describe what you did? Your answer is currently incomplete.

Comment: see function ol [IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401705/ordered-list-does-not-work-on-ie7-olli)

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property value: list-style-type:lower-alpha;